# What am I? Better guess fast, the clock's ticking

Tags: riddle, geography, outer-space

You can come into us, you can walk our stairs,
You can click pictures with us, but no-one will care.
If our real purpose is asked, we're meant to tell the time,
But not using us for that must be made a crime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> The Jantar Mantar monument of Jaipur, Rajasthan.

You can come into us.

> Tourists are allowed to enter.

You can walk our stairs.

> There are stairs that are climbed to reach the instruments.

You can click pictures with us, but no-one will care.

> There is no prohibition against taking photos.

If our real purpose is asked, we're meant to tell the time.

> The instruments were used for astronomy and for predictions of what astronomical events will happen and when.

But not using us for that must be made a crime.

> You must not use the monuments for any purpose except to visit and take pictures.

Comment: That's probably true of many places, for example-Big Ben.

Comment: @Anachor: But there wouldn't be an Astronomy tag for the Big Ben.

Comment: @Amar A puzzle shouldn't rely on its tag to generate a answer.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> The Pyramids

You can come into us, you can walk our stairs,

> visitors to the pyramids can climb the stairs inside

You can click pictures with us, but no-one will care.

> There are thousands of photos of the pyramids, so no-one will be bothered with your holiday snaps

If our real purpose is asked, we're meant to tell the time,

> The air shafts in the pyramids are built to align with the constellation Orion and the Sphinx's gaze marks the point of sunrise at the equinox.

But not using us for that must be made a crime.

> Too much tourism is leading to the erosion of the pyramids.

Comment: You're close but this isn't the structure that I'm looking for. :). Besides I don't think the real purpose for pyramids is to tell the time.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> A smart watch?

You can come into us,

> Put your wrist in it

you can walk our stairs,

> Count steps when running

You can click pictures with us, but no-one will care.

> Not sure but I guess there exist ones with a camera

If our real purpose is asked, we're meant to tell the time,

> Because it's a watch

But not using us for that must be made a crime.

> This is maybe a popular opinion?

Comment: Good answer, but there's a geography and an astronomy tag.

Comment: Aah I missed that. Then the answer is maybe some structure that functions as a sundial

Comment: I initially thought of that too.